# NetBeans and Eclipse not recognizing maven dependencies

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, eclipse-oxygen, netbeans-8.2

The IDEs are not recognizing the dependencies.

I've already gone through several other similar questions on StackOverflow but so far nothing has worked for me.

I have a maven project in which **I've already declared** *mysql-connector-java-8.0.8-dmr* **and** *Gson-2.8.0* as dependencies, but for some reason I still get this errors:

> - java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world
> - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson

I've tried it with NetBeans 8.2 and Eclipse Oxygen 1a
I'm using JRE 1.8.0_152

It happens at lines:

> - con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world", "root", "");
> - Gson gson = new Gson();

Here's the POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.listamaya</groupId>
    <artifactId>listamaya</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.8-dmr</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Does `mvn clean install` work?

Comment: Yes, it does. I run the app and everything works up until it gets to those lines.

Comment: @JorgeZ - Are you running the applications within the IDEs (NetBeans and Eclipse), or are you trying to run them from the command line?

Comment: I'm running it from within the IDEs.

Comment: @JorgeZ - In Eclipse, when you open your pom.xml, select the mysql-connector-java dependency on the "Dependencies" tab, and click the "Properties..." button does it look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJCz9.png)? (p.s. Remember to use an "@ mention" when you reply to a comment.)

Comment: So your packaging is broken.  This is notoriously difficult to get right in maven for new programmers. You explicitly need to handle the classpath.

Comment: @GordThompson - Yes, it looks exactly like that.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - How do I get it right?

Comment: Show your pom.xml.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - See the pom.xml above.

Comment: Check the war (if the jars are in that zip file), and check whether the war is deployed in glassfish. Especially there not being an other old app on the same port.

Comment: I hope you know that mysql-connector-java-8.0.8-dmr is a development version that is not ready for production use. The latest released version of MySQL Connector/J is version 5.1.44.

Comment: @JoopEggen - It's being deploy on Tomcat and it's the only app on the server.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Show output of `jar tvf your.war`.

Comment: Is this project publicly available?  If not, consider putting it on github.

Comment: @All - Thanks everybody, I finally just created a project from scratch and everything works so far. I have no idea what was wrong.